# How to create project integrating Ogre3D with OpenCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, ogre3d

Sorry if this sounds like a basic question.
But I am doing a personal project where I wish to use OpenCV for camera tracking and Ogre3D for rendering.

However, I am not sure how to create the project to utilize both libraries in a proper manner.
Please help. Maybe a skeleton template?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get skeleton template from the code of libhand library. you can get it here: http://www.libhand.org/